# Merging data on api gateway level or microservice level?

Tags: microservices, aws-api-gateway, distributed-system, api-gateway

I am using API gateway in order to make microservice resource publicly available.

I have the following situation (simplified as possible)

**Microservice A** - serve provides product prices on
/product-prices/{id}

**Microservice B** - provides product availability on
/product-availability/{id}

In order to get product price and availability I would either need to do the following

a) have Microservice A be dependent on Microservice B and have
/product-prices-and-availability/{id} endpoint

or

b) have API gateway consume Microservice A and Microservice B in order to provide price end availability resource

Basically my question is should I merge data on microservice level or on api gateway level?

Comment: Whose microservices?  Are they your services, or are they outside your control?  Why are they separate, now?  What is the likelihood that your caller needs one without the other?  Possibly, your simplification of the question is obscuring something more significant.

Comment: My microservices. I appreciate your opinion, and i am currently working on refactoring parts of micoservice in order to increase their level of autonomicity, but I am thinking about this a lot lately and would like to get opinion is it better for microservice to depend on other microservice or api to depend on multiple microservices?

Comment: i don't think aws api gateway currently supports orchestration / response aggregation

Comment: @Nicholas aws api gateway supports it

Comment: can you show me how to do this?? are there any docs / examples which demonstrate that my method request is being sliced into two integration requests which are routed to separate backends and my method response aggregates two integration response. thanks!